# How to manually install the EPiServer Scheduling Service

Tags: episerver

I'm trying to manually install the EPiServer scheduler service on a web server using installutil.

I run this at the command promp:
C:\WINDOWS\Microsoft.NET\Framework64\v2.0.50727\installutil D:\EPiServerSchedulerService\EPiServer.SchedulerSvc.exe

And get an error:
**No public installers with the RunInstallerAttribute.Yes attribute could be found in the D:\EPiServerSchedulerService\EPiServer.SchedulerSvc.exe assembly.**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It turns out it's not possible to do this with installutil, the service doesn't support it. I used the installer EPiServerShared.msi which is included with the EPiServer CMS downloads.

I wrote [a quick blog post about it](http://www.jonathansewell.co.uk/index.php/2010/09/07/installing-the-episerver-scheduler-service/).